# How can I check whether element exists based on the classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I mentioned in the title of my question, my element doesn't have `id` attribute. So how can I check whether it exists or not?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="classname">something</div>
```

---

**Note1:** I can do that if there is a `id` attribute like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("idname");
if ( el ){
    console.log("exists");
} else {
    console.log("not");
}
```

But I want to know how can I do that based on the class name .. is it possible?

**Note2:** I use *jQuery*.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla javascript (without jQuery or any other lib):

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('className')
var first = els[0]
```

*Notice that this is an array, since there could be many elements with that class*

With jQuery:

```js
var els = $('.className')
```

this will result in a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/) instead of a DOM element, so you better use [the length() method](https://api.jquery.com/length/) for checking existence.

Answer (score 1):

check with `.length` ,coz className will give you array list if exist

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
if ( el.length > 0 ){
    console.log("exists");
} else {
    console.log("not");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

If using jQuery, please use class selector.
https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($('.classname').length > 0)
{
    alert('exist');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
if ($(".classname")[0]){ // do stuff }
```

This will use the jquery selector to grab all items with that class name, and attempt to access the first result (in position 0).  This will fail if there are no elements with this class name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
if (el) {
    console.log("exists");
} else {
    console.log("not");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.this will show how to get the class in  automatically `document.ready` or , when a button clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="classname">something</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // you can check the class name in document ready or in any other event like click


    //this will show all the class names of div when document ready.
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var the_class_name = $("div").attr('class');
  alert(the_class_name); // this put to show you the classs names

  if(the_class_name == "classneme")
  {
   //do your coding
  }
  else
  {
   //do your coding
  }
 });



 //if you want to get the class name when a button click and check if the class is exist

     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("div").click(function(){
       var classnames = $(this).attr('class');
       alert(classnames);

       if (classnames == "your_class_name") 
       {
        // your code here
       }
       else
       {
        // your code here
       }
      });
     });

</script>

</html>
```